# Program stopping when running sklearn KNN prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm working on a Recommendation System and I have to test the K-Nearest Neighbors method to fit and predict my results. My program runs perfectly until the predict_proba

```
# Create model
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)

# Fit model
model.fit(X_train_sparse, y_train)

# Predict
antitrain_predictions_probs = model.predict_proba(X_antitrain_sparse)
```

after this line the program simply stops without any error. It also happens when using model.predict(X_antitrain_sparse). Anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try adding the `print(antitrain_predictions_probs)` and seeing what happens?

Comment: yes, nothing happens, as I said, any line after the predict line doesnt run

Comment: KNeighbors support sparse matrices in `fit()` but I dont think it supports sparse in any other functions, as its not mentioned anywhere in docs other than `fit()`. So maybe try dense matrices in `predict()` and `predict_proba()`

Comment: can you add the data in order to reproduce the probelm? Also, what's your sklearn version ?

Comment: the version of sklearn is 0.19.1